# Invisible Progress Bar not showing up through code

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm making a project Android application that takes an image URL, downloads the image and displays the image. In case of an image of bigger size i want to show the user an indeterminate progress that the image is being downloading.

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView downloadedImg;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Handler handler;


    public void downloadImage(View view){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap myimage;
        try {
            myimage = task.execute("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/high_tech_earth-wallpaper-2880x1800.jpg").get();
            downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myimage);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadedImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        handler = new Handler();

    }

    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return mybitmap;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    downloadedImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void reset(View view){
        downloadedImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.syeddanish.downloadingimages.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="downloadImage"
        android:text="Download Image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue i'm facing is that i want the progress bar to become visible when the download starts(i.e when "Download Image button is pressed"). I'm trying to do this in two ways i.e

1. By using `progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in the start of
   the onClick method of "Download Image" button.
   or
2. By using `progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in theonPreExecute() method of the ASyncTask but the progress bardoes not shows up using any of the above mentioned ways.

Can anyone please point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: i guess the problem is with xml, fill_parent is deprecated use match parent instead or use a specific height and width

Comment: I see no wrong in your code. Maybe it's the color of the `progressbar` you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try put `downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myimage);` inside `onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)`handler and change:

```
myimage = task.execute("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/high_tech_earth-wallpaper-2880x1800.jpg").get();
```

to:

```
task.execute("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/high_tech_earth-wallpaper-2880x1800.jpg");
```

also put `Bitmap myimage;` as global variable on your Asynctask class and change:

```
Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return mybitmap;
```

to:

```
myimage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

on doInBackground

Comment: glad can help :)

Comment: Very kind of you 

Answer (score 2):

Does this code compile and run without `NetworkOnMainThreadException`? 
Your problem is the usage of `get()`

In this part:

```
        Bitmap myimage;
    try {
        myimage = task.execute("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/high_tech_earth-wallpaper-2880x1800.jpg").get();
        downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myimage);
    }
```

you try to get an image from `task.execute(...)`, but `task.get()` as per docu:

> ```
>    [...]Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.[...]
> ```

So you are waiting for your "task" to execute on the main thread and blocking it, until done. Because of that, your progress
is never visible, because the UI-Thread is blocked. And once your task finishes,
the progress is set back to be invisible.

Moreover, do not reinvent the weel. Use one of the libraries available out there
for image downloading and caching.

For example: [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Both also provide the functionality to use a (1) fallback and (2) loading image.

---

If you still like to try it on your own, then do not do the *Pokémon- "gotta catch'em all"* way of catching your exceptions, but instead, handle specific `Exceptions` that might occur and display a message to the user, send it your crash tracker, etc. Only catch exceptions that you expect to be thrown, otherwise...let it crash.

I do not see, why you should catch an exception there.

**AsyncTask, Activities and memory leaks**

Next is, that `AsyncTasks` are not tidily coupled to the `Activities` 
life cycle. When you run your task and it executes in background, but 
your activity finishes, this task will still be alive and leaks a reference to your activity. This causes the memory leaks, because the GC can't properly do it's job, to clean after you.

Make your AsyncTask at least a static class and **stop/kill** the task, once your activity finishes.

**Multiple Tasks**

Next thing, check if you already download the image, once the user clicked the button, or you're going to create multiple tasks.

So, make your ImageDownloader a member of your activity and check if it is already executing or done. (Take it out of your method and put it below the activity class head). When your activity calls `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`, kill the task with fire.

Be aware of **orientation changes**, too.

**Android Task API instead of AsyncTask**

I highly recommend to use the android task api. (`com.google.android.gms.tasks`)

It works very well for tasks, both running on the Main- or Workerthreads. Include continuations, provides `Future` like functionality and can be coupled with Activities.

References: [gms Task API Doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task)

Comment: thanks for your elaborated answer. I am trying to understand what you have pointed out but i just want to say that i am a beginner and don't know much. I have just started learning android and this is one of my first apps which i am trying to make to understand the concepts of threading. So i will appreciate if you will guide me on the base level.

Comment: by the way thanks for taking out your precious time :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `pBar.setAlpha(1f);`

It helped when I'm stuck on a similar problem.